# how to add a new map or row to sharedpreferences file

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I am building an app to store data in a shared preferences file
The problem is that i want to know how can i add a new row (map) in sharedpref file,but not edit the same map or update the same map keys,values pair

when i checked the sharedpref file in it's location after adding new data,i found the same map is being updated and didn't add a new map(or row)

MainActivity.kt

```
 //start sharedpreference to save data
    val sharedPrefFile = "goldinvesto"  //filename to save
    val collectdata:SharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(sharedPrefFile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val editor:SharedPreferences.Editor=collectdata.edit()

         editor.putString("start_date",save_date)
         editor.putString("amount",save_amount_txt)
         editor.putString("currency",spin.selectedItem.toString())
         editor.putString("karat",spin2.selectedItem.toString())
         editor.putString("enter_price",save_enter_price)
         editor.apply()
         editor.commit()
```

sharedpref file location:
[image]

Comment: To save data in row/column type , it is suggested to use sqlite

Comment: If you want to stick with SharedPreference, each map is a separate file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in SharedPreferences because it is a file based on a single map with key/values.

You have to use a database, with SQLite, Room, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For saving more than one map you must provide unique keys for it's values which also must be unique for each of the map, for example:

```
editor.putString("start_date_1",save_date_1)
editor.putString("amount_1",save_amount_txt_1)
editor.putString("currency_1",spin.selectedItem_1.toString())
editor.putString("start_date_2",save_date_2)
editor.putString("amount_2",save_amount_txt_2)
editor.putString("currency_2",spin.selectedItem_2.toString())
editor.putString("start_date_3",save_date_3)
editor.putString("amount_3",save_amount_txt_3)
editor.putString("currency_3",spin.selectedItem_3.toString())
```

and so on, but it's a bad practice to store a large amount of data in shared preferences and you should use sqlite or room or store your data in files